# Table of contents hiding other elements

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-panel">
    <h3>Table of Contents</h3>
        <ul id="menu-toc" class="menu-toc">
            <li><a href="landingpage.html">Home</a></li>
            <li style="border-top: #FFF solid 1px;" class="menu-toc-current"><a href="index.html">Biography</a></li>
            <li><a href="extra_curricula.html">Extra Curricular</a></li>
            <li><a href="favorites.html">Favorites</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <h2>Biography</h2>    
    <p>THIS INFO SHOWS UP WITH HEAVY CSS EDITING</p>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-panel {
    background: #013E7D;
    width: 240px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    margin: 0px;
}



.menu-panel h3 {
    font-family:Roboto;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    padding: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
} 

.menu-toc {
    list-style: none;
}

.menu-toc li a {
       font-family:Roboto;
       display: block;
       color: #C0C0C0;
       font-size: 1.1em;
       line-height: 3.5;
       padding: 0 20px;
       cursor: pointer;
       background: #013E7D;
       border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}

.menu-toc li a:hover,
.menu-toc li.menu-toc-current a {
    background: #000000;
}

.menu-panel div {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.menu-panel div a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    color: #bc0b0b;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
} 


@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .no-js .menu-panel {
      display: none;
    }

    .no-js .container {
        padding: 0;
    }


@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .menu-panel,
    .content {
         font-size: 75%;
    }

    .main {
         margin-left:797px;
         position:fixed;
         font-family:Roboto;
    }
```

So basically I need to get the table of contents to be static so all other elements go around it!! I have been trying to fix this and it will not work. If you could help me it would help a lot! Thank you

Comment: Things "go around" only elements that are floated, so `menu-toc` must have a `float:` style.  See [this](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#float-position)

Comment: @JimGarrison That didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu-panel {
  background: #013E7D;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
}
```

in css removing the position and adding the float results in horizontally aligned blocks. see also http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXJRWx

Comment: Alright that worked, sorta. The rest of the styling for the table of contents is gone now. Thank you!! After getting rid of the position the bottom half of the table of contents is gone.  @lkiraly

Comment: you could also use something like [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to have a clean start. @a-j-davis